# I'm trying to get a month's worth of weather data from API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I'm building a React app which uses the Dark Sky weather API. I'm trying to get a month's worth of weather data. Then I am trying to iterate through every hour of each day to see if the weather falls below 62 degrees or above 75. If it does, it will increment a counter for each range. I managed to get the total times it falls below 62 or above 75. But I am also trying to get the total amount of both for each individual day and I can't figure out how. My initial thought is to push data from each day into the state using the getDailyData() method. However, when I console log the heatingData or acData, it doesn't contain 31 days of data. It contains several hundred duplicates. Here's what I am so far. Any help would be appreciated.

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import DisplayCount from "./components/DisplayCount"
    import axios from "axios";

    class App extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          heatingData: [],
          acData: [],
          airConditioningCount: 0,
          heatingCount: 0
        }
      }

      componentDidMount = () => {
        this.getDailyData();
      }

      getDailyData = () => {

        for (let i = 1; i <= 31; i++) {

          const proxy = `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/`;
          const apiURL = `https://api.darksky.net/forecast/8b01861d3b06ab86ba285ef08d52c88d/45.5898,-122.5951,2018-05-${[i] < 10 ? "0" + [i] : [i]}T00:00:00`;

          axios(proxy + apiURL)
            .then(response => {
              return response.data.hourly.data;
            })
            .then(res => {
              this.setState(prevState => ({
                acData: [...prevState.acData, res],
                heatingData: [...prevState.heatingData, res]
              }))
              res.forEach(id => {
              if (id.temperature > 75) {
                this.setState(prevState =>({
                    airConditioningCount: prevState.airConditioningCount + 1
                }))
              } else if (id.temperature < 62){
                this.setState(prevState =>({
                  heatingCount: prevState.heatingCount + 1
                }))
                }
              })
            })
        }
      }

      render() {
        return (
          <div className="App">
            <h1 className="title">HVAC Report</h1>
            <h3 className="subtitle">(Month of May 2018)</h3>
            <div className="display-container">
              <DisplayCount
                countTitle={"Total AC Count"}
                countTotal={this.state.airConditioningCount} />
              <DisplayCount
                countTitle={"Total Heating Count"}
                countTotal={this.state.heatingCount} />
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

const DisplayCount = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className="display-count">
      <h2>{props.countTitle}</h2>
      <p>{props.countTotal}</p>
    </div>
  );
}


    export default App;
```

Comment: Something is wrong with your code. I tried to make codesendbox with it and nothing gets rendered. If you could make codesendbox for us to use it would be much easier to help you.

Comment: Weird, I think it has to do with the "axios" package not added on the package.json file. But I added it and it works now

https://codesandbox.io/s/9y335lr3vo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I did what you wanted. I made function that is making an object that has keys for every single day in the month. So it goes `var month = { 1: {}, 2: {}, 3: {}}` and so on... Inside every object you have above and below keys that are showing how many times did temperature rise above 75 or went below 62 on that day. Second thing, the API that you are using does not return proper time in milliseconds, so I needed to fix that. I think you will see why...

This is a codesendbox link where you can find the solution: https://codesandbox.io/s/0393374vqn

Comment: Dude, thank you so much! It worked like a charm. You are awesome :)